# Sentiment search engine

Tags: tool-request, sentiment-analysis, search-engine

Sometimes I want to know what is the mainstream sentiment about a product/service/person/anything.

For instance:

- is the game [GTA V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V) considered by players as entertaining or boring?
- are [selfie sticks](https://timethemoment.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/looq-s.jpg?w=337&h=253) considered by most as cool or uncool?
- etc

I could run a sentiment analysis but this would take a lot of time, especially to find source data.

Is there a kind of search engine that would crawl the web in permanence, and allow me to just type the name of something and get the sentiments for it?

It should be usable even for very new things.

Bonus if the sentiments are drillable by country/age/etc.

---

[image: Sentiment search engine]

Answer (score 5):

The first source of raw interactions that fit your needs that comes to mind is **Twitter**.

## NCSU's Tweet Sentiment Visualization

http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/tweet_app/ seems pretty good in that it allows you to enter keywords and get a graph of recent tweets graphed on axes (pleasant/unpleasant and active/inactive). It also has some pretty extensive documentation about how to interpret and how the system arrives at the results. Clicking on a data item shows the raw tweet:

[image: NCSU's Tweet Sentiment Visualization]

## Lists of tools

- http://matei.org/ithink/2012/02/08/a-list-of-twitter-sentiment-analysis-tools/ has a list of other *Twitter Sentiment Analysis Tools*
- http://www.khwrites.com/online-sentiment-analysis-social-media-monitoring-tools/ has a list of *free* *Online Sentiment Analysis: Social Media Monitoring Tools*

---

Another thought would be to ingest tweets on your own and [use one of many Sentiment APIs](http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-20-sentiment-analysis-apis/) to arrive at your own results.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually been working on something very similar; a search engine for restaurants in London. The search engine crawls popular social media platforms (TripAdvisor, Open Table etc.) on a daily basis and allows users to get an overall view for a given restaurant based on written comments from EVERY review.

You can also search for a particular dish / cuisine / drink across all restaurants in London. The results are generated by analyzing every sentence from review for every restaurant in order to determine which places are the most highly rated.

See http://sentimentsearch.com/#/free

I plan to scale this out for other domains like mobile phones and electronics.

Comment: Is there a way to share the data or do you have plans to do so?

Comment: The platform is still in development and therefore I do not have plans to share the data as yet. However doing so is pretty straight forward. The data could easily be made available for download using an API.

Comment: There is no such thing as "too late" here, great up-to-date answer are always welcome :-)